# User selects language on login page using form django

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-views, forms

I have a login page with the following form:

```
  <form class="login-form" name="LoginForm" action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
    <p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ form.username.label_tag }} </td>
                <td>{{ form.username }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ form.password.label_tag }}</td>
                <td>{{ form.password }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </p>
    <input class="button button-small" type="submit" value="Login" />
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
  </form>
  <a>English</a>
  <a>French</a>
```

and I have a forms.py that looks like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm 
from django import forms

class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label="Username", max_length=30, 
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'username'}))
    password = forms.CharField(label="Password", max_length=30, 
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'password', 'name': 'password', 'class': 'form-control'}))
```

and urls.py that looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from stellar.forms import LoginForm
from stellar.views import index2
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('example.urls')),
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html', 'authentication_form': LoginForm}, name = 'login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'next_page': '/login'}),
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
]
```

Basically, if the user clicks on English or French the language of the page should change. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make another form below the authenticated one like [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view).

```
{% load i18n %}

<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}

...
```

Follow the instructions from there and you'll be fine!

Let me know if that worked.

Comment: Glad I could help. Mark this answer as correct and... happy coding!

Comment: I had to wait a bit of time before I could mark it as correct

Comment: That's OK! No problem!